# Looping through Methods & Threads

Tags: java, multithreading, android-activity, android-asynctask

On the startup of the activity I would like to loop through the below methods. I want to only move to the next method once the each method or thread had finished. Once the Check game method has finished I would like the loop to start again.

How can I achieve this?

Load game method ()
Runnable timer (Thread)
Check game method ()

Comment: You need to be a little more clear about what you want to achieve, and if you have code that isn't working

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html

You could use thread.join(); to wait for another thread to end and then the thread will start up again after it finishes 
such as

```
function()
{
Thread t = new Thread();
t.start();
t.join();  //waits for run to finish
}
public void run()
{
  dosomethinghere();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to wait for multiple asynchronous tasks for finish, then create a [CountDownLatch](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) object initialized with the number of tasks, pass this object to the tasks, and call await() on the original thread. The other threads must call countDown() on the CountDownLatch object when they are finished with their tasks.

> A CountDownLatch initialized to N can be used to make one thread wait until N threads have completed some action, or some action has been completed N times.